# Need a fix to "Page blocks cache" in Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Tags: category, cache, ce-1.9.0.1, navigation

It seems there is a bug with the cache in Page blocks.

Here is the description of the problem:
The problem shows first in menu navigation, if I click on a menu category, it gets active, but once I click on an item inside this category, the category is NOT active anymore although in the URL, the same category is still there.

Sometimes, when I navigate between categories and then click on different items in different categories, the older categories get active (highlighted) although the current item I am looking at does NOT below to this category!

Once I disabled cache for Page blocks, there is no problem anymore.

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.0.1 server and apache2.

Does somebody have a fix for this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the bug!!!

If you go to `/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php` and go to line 57 you will find:

```
$this->addData(array(
    'cache_lifetime' => false,
));
```

This code did NOT exist in Magento 1.7.0.1 (where I didn't have such a problem).

After I have overridden this class in a custom block and removed like 57, the "Page blocks HTML." is active again and the problems with the navigation menu disappeared.

I hope Magento team will fix this base bug ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I also just encountered this bug. Rewriting the class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` as suggested by @Akram would work, but is rather interfering. A better solution as seen in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24434521/719023) would be to add the following to your `local.xml` file:

```
<reference name="catalog.topnav">
    <action method="unsetData">
        <key>cache_lifetime</key>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Mind that this disables the cache for this specific top navigation block completely. If performance really matters, it may be a better idea to rewrite the block and add the category and/or product ID to the cache keys.